# Flavius Josephus: $J(2^i)=1~\forall i\geq 1$ (An Inductive Proof)

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I'm asked to "[u]se induction to show that $J(2^i)=1$ for all $i\geq 1$. Where do I start?

---

Here $J(n)$ is the last position of $n$ baskets with balls in them for which every second basket, starting from position $0$, is emptied until one basket is left, namely this last basket is the position number. In [other words](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JosephusProblem.html), and I'm sorry for not being clear the first time, prove that $L(2^i, 2)$ is always $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the task. Instead of emptying baskets, we can simply remove them. So they do not need to be filled with balls or kittens or anything.

> **Problem:** There are $n$ baskets lined up. Remove every other basket. Repeat this step for the remaining baskets until only one basket is left. *Prove*, that the left over basket was originally the first one.

I am not quite sure, where you got stuck. The answer to "Where do I start?" is, as always with induction: With the base case! In this case you are supposed to prove this for $n\geq 1$, so prove it for $n=1$, that is for $2^n=2$ baskets.

Then you need to prove the induction step. Think about what happens in the first iteration. Then, after removing every other basket, there are only half as many, so you can apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I liked the basket-emptying story rather than the "elimination" concept.